# ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I use windows 7 and python 2.7

When I used py2exe to make an .exe file I get the error;

Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "mainpy", line 17, in`

`File "main.py", line 17, in`

`File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module`

`File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module`

`File "logging_init_.pyc", line 26, in`

`File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module`

`File "weakref.pyc", line 14, in`

`ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref`

The same code could be used to make an .exe file in another computer so there is nothing wrong with the code in main.py. The minor environmental difference may cause this problem. I used pycharm, python 2.7.10 and py2exe 0.6.9. On another computer all other config are the same except using sublimetext instead of pycharm.
Could anyone please tell me how to fix that?

Another tricky thing is that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the library does not exists for the other computer.Please check whether the library exists or not.

Comment: how to check which library is missing?

Comment: Some libraries which are not inbuilt which you have downloaded for the program , check on idle import the library if it shows error then the library does not exists otherwise it does